# How to get an array in the object on the client side?

Tags: python, arrays, soap, spyne

I would like to get an array in the object on the client side, but instead I need to access dictionary like this:

```
 response.BODY["string"]
```

Preferred solution would be:

```
 response.BODY
```

For code below:

```
class ServerResponse(ComplexModel):
    BODY = Array(String)

    def __init__(self, BODY):
        self.BODY = BODY

class SomeService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(_returns=ServerResponse)
    def reportEvent(ctx):
        return ServerResponse(["1", "2"])
```

I am new to spyne so any help is very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` creates what's called a *wrapped* array. If you need an unwrapped one you can try:

```
class ServerResponse(ComplexModel):
    BODY = String(max_occurs='unbounded')

    def __init__(self, BODY):
        self.BODY = BODY
```

This will repeat the `<BODY>` tag instead of repeating the `<string>` tag *inside* the `<BODY>` tag.

However, this is not the canonical way of dealing with arrays in SOAP world. Some clients auto-detect wrapped arrays. If yours doesn't I recommend to either change client libraries or learning to live with it.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect also on the client side.